# Android: Gesture recognition from frontal camera

Tags: android, camera, tracking, gesture-recognition, motion

I'm wondering if anyone could direct me to any useful APIs they may know that will track movement from the front camera on an Android device. Preferably, it'll be able to detect a hand for example and then track the movement from there on.

I've looked around and found a couple of interesting things but would appreciate if anyone could recommend anything they may know of that would do the trick. So far, 'nuidroid' looks most appealing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The Android library, HandWave, might be another good example that has the functionality to do this.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/kritts/HandWave

Answer (score 0):

Nuidroid does not use RGB for skeletal tracking or gesture recognition, it uses kinect-like sensors (Asus Xtion, for example). But one of its modules allows for face tracking, though you need to contact the developers via e-mail to provide it for testing.